# Define script tags dynamically on react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My project has to use two different templates (user/panel). So I need to define Javascript tags dynamically. I tried so much thing but not solved my problem. On last solution at below code, sometimes scripts loading correct sometimes not. I got various console errors.

How can I load java script tags like html page.

```
 import '../assets/css/bootstrap.css';
 import '../assets/css/style.css';
 import '../assets/css/responsive.css';
 import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
 import {Helmet} from 'react-helmet';
export function Home(){
 var loadScript = function(src) {
        var tag = document.createElement('script');
        tag.async = true;
        tag.src = src;
        document.body.appendChild(tag);                 
  }    
  loadScript('./assets/js/jquery.js');
  loadScript('./assets/js/bootstrap.min.js');
  loadScript('./assets/js/popper.min.js');      
  loadScript('./assets/js/jquery-ui.js');
  loadScript('./assets/js/jquery.fancybox.js');
return(
        <div>
 <Helmet>
         <title>{model.Title}</title>
         <meta name="description" content={model.Desc}/>
         <meta name="keywords" content={model.Keys}/>
         <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum- 
scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"></meta>
        
         </Helmet>   
        .......
        </div>
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call the `loadScript` script inside a `useEffect` and also should remove the script when you unmount the component.

```js
import '../assets/css/bootstrap.css';
import '../assets/css/style.css';
import '../assets/css/responsive.css';
import React,{ useEffect } from 'react';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';

const useScript = (src) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.async = true;
    tag.src = src;
    document.body.appendChild(tag);
    
    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(tag);
    }
  }, [src])

}

export function Home(){
  useScript('./assets/js/jquery.js');
  useScript('./assets/js/bootstrap.min.js');
  useScript('./assets/js/popper.min.js');      
  useScript('./assets/js/jquery-ui.js');
  useScript('./assets/js/jquery.fancybox.js');

return(
        <div>
 <Helmet>
         <title>{model.Title}</title>
         <meta name="description" content={model.Desc}/>
         <meta name="keywords" content={model.Keys}/>
         <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum- 
scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"></meta>
        
         </Helmet>   
        .......
        </div>
)

}
```

Comment: After I change 'tag.async' from true to false my problem solved. Every script works fine. Thank you very much for your helps.